# java swing drag & drop linux: DragSourceListener.dragDropEnd not called

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, drag

I am trying to implement a drag & drop behavior to a `jtabbedpane`.
It's working well on my Windows 10, but not so much on a Debian 12 (openjdk 17 on the Debian).

Here is a minimal test case:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.dnd.DnDConstants;
import java.awt.dnd.DragGestureEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DragGestureListener;
import java.awt.dnd.DragSource;
import java.awt.dnd.DragSourceDragEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DragSourceDropEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DragSourceEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DragSourceListener;
import java.awt.dnd.InvalidDnDOperationException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class DnDTestCase extends JFrame {
  JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
  public DnDTestCase() {
    tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    getContentPane().add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    tabbedPane.addTab("New tab", null, panel, null);

    this.setSize(320, 240);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    initDnd();
  }

  void initDnd() {
    final DragSourceListener dsl = new DragSourceListener() {
      @Override
      public void dragEnter(DragSourceDragEvent e) {}
      @Override
      public void dragExit(DragSourceEvent e) {}
      @Override
      public void dragOver(DragSourceDragEvent e) {}
      @Override
      public void dragDropEnd(DragSourceDropEvent e) {
        System.out.println("dragDropEnd()");
      }
      @Override
      public void dropActionChanged(DragSourceDragEvent e) {}
    };

    final DragGestureListener dgl = new DragGestureListener() {
      @Override
      public void dragGestureRecognized(DragGestureEvent e) {
        System.out.println("dragGestureRecognized()");
        try {
          e.startDrag(DragSource.DefaultMoveDrop,
            new Transferable() {
              @Override
              public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) {
                return null;
              }
              @Override
              public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
                return null;
              }
              @Override
              public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
                return true;
              }
            },
            dsl);
        } catch (InvalidDnDOperationException idoe) {
          idoe.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    };

    DragSource ds = new DragSource();
    ds.createDefaultDragGestureRecognizer(tabbedPane, DnDConstants.ACTION_MOVE, dgl);

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new DnDTestCase().setVisible(true));
  }
}
```

Here it is on `Windows`.[JFrame+JtabPane]

[image]

Basically, you can drag and drop the tab to the window itself, and also to an empty space outside of the `JFrame`, and in both cases on Windows the `dragDropEnd` function is triggered when the mouse button is released. So it displays `dragDropEnd()` in the terminal. Which is nice.

However, on the `Linux` run, it `dragDropEnd` is triggered only if the mouse cursor is over a `JFrame` (the original one or even another one, it doesn't really matter, apparently).

If the mouse button is released over an empty space (=not a `JFrame` — or even a `JDialog` probably), it doesn't trigger anything UNTIL the mouse cursor is moved back over the `JFrame`. So for some reason, the event is not generated if the mouse is not over the `JFrame`?

Is there something obvious I am doing in a bad way?

Comment: I do not reproduce the (mis)behavior you describe on openjdk 1.8.0_362-b08, CentOS Stream 8.  I see "dragDropEnd()" displayed in the console as soon as I drop, whether that's inside or outside the the application's JFrame.

Comment: I speculate that the results you observe may be associated with your window manager / desktop settings.  For example, if you have configured your Linux desktop such that focus follows the mouse, with the result that your application's JFrame loses focus when you move the mouse out of it, then it is plausible that the drop event would not fire until the frame regained focus.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks. I am going to add a focus listener to see what is going on on that side. My Debian is using KDE.

Comment: @JohnBollinger
So, it's losing the focus indeed. Thanks already for that!

Now,  I need to find a workaround!

Comment: I'm glad to have helped.  For the record, I am also using KDE.

Comment: a tabbedPane.addFocusListener/focusLost(){tabbedPane.requestFocus()} regains the focus but the drop event is still not triggered (besides, my requestFocus() is obviously quite crude, I would need to change it obviously)

Comment: @JohnBollinger KDE in your CentOS? I would need to try it. And maybe a JDK 8 too.

Comment: Yes, KDE in my CentOS.  I switched when RedHat moved to Gnome 3, which I cannot stand.  KDE used to be supported directly by RHEL (versions 7 and below), and it is available from EPEL since version 8.  I think it's still in Fedora.